# How to invoke a method of a groovy class from Java - Method name and parameter in string format

Tags: java, methods, groovy

I have a Java program which accepts some string input in the below format:

```
setData("hello")
```

Also, I have a groovy script say "*sample.groovy*", it is a groovy file in the following sample format:

> ```
> class sample
> {
>     def doOperation()
>     {
>         println("Inside doOperation()")
>     }
>
>     def setData(String str)
>     {  
>         println("Incoming data : " + str)
>     }
>  }
> ```

---

From the Java class, create an object of above groovy class named : sampleObj.

I have to invoke **sampleObj.setData("hello")** from my Java application using the input string say "setData("hello")".

Then how can I invoke this method?

Comment: Do you invoke groovy script from java using javax.script?

Comment: Can you clarify your intentions? With some example, maybe.

Comment: @User I've answered your question, though I wrote the code in Groovy, the same will work the same in Java. Did it not work for you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is exactly the kind of problem that [GroovyShell](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/api/groovy/lang/GroovyShell.html) solves.

Here's an example:

```
import groovy.transform.Canonical
import org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilerConfiguration

@Canonical
class ScriptState {
    String data
}

abstract class MyScript extends Script {
    void setData(String data) {
        binding.state.data = data
    }
}

def state = new ScriptState()
def cc = new CompilerConfiguration(scriptBaseClass: MyScript.class.name)

def shell = new GroovyShell(MyScript.classLoader, new Binding(state: state), cc)

shell.evaluate('println "Running script"; setData "The Data"')

assert state.data == 'The Data'

println state
```

Running this will print:

```
Running script
ScriptState(The Data)
```

I based this example on the [Groovy Goodness](http://mrhaki.blogspot.se/2011/11/groovy-goodness-create-our-own-script.html) example.

Normally, you don't need to set the classloader as I did in `MyScript.classLoader`... I only needed to do this because I ran this as a script, to the script class would not be visible to the GroovyShell's script classloader if I didn't do that.

**EDIT**

After the question was heavily edited, it seem the problem is that **you don't know which class the Java object to call from the script will have**.

In that case, just change the `MyScript` class to do something like this:

```
abstract class MyScript extends Script {
    def methodMissing(String name, args) {
        // this will call any method called inside the script
        // on the sample Object
        binding.sampleObject."$name"(*args)
    }
}
```

Now, when creating the GroovyShell:

```
def shell = new GroovyShell(
    MyScript.classLoader,
    new Binding(sampleObject: new Sample()),
    cc)
```

Running this code:

```
shell.evaluate('doOperation(); setData "The Data"')
```

will print the expected:

```
Inside doOperation()
Incoming data : The Data
```